# Why is it showing me that connection has not established?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

Why java is showing this output for every port connections And is it require any thing like basic frame or package in java other than these.i am working on basic server client program first is client and second is server.I tried basic code for only connection.but it shows this output every time

```
 import java.io.*;
            import java.net.*;
            class DateClient
            {
                public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
                {
                    Socket soc=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),5217);        
                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()  ));
                    System.out.println(in.readLine());
                }    
            }




import java.net.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import java.util.*;
            class DateServer
            {
                public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
                {
                    ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(5217);
                    while(true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Waiting For Connection ...");
                        Socket soc=s.accept();
                        DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
                        out.writeBytes("Server Date: " + (new Date()).toString() + "\n");
                        out.close();
                        soc.close();
                    }
                }
            }


        THIS IS OUTPUT

         output:=
                Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: conn
                ect
                        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
                        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at DateClient.main(DateClient.java:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the DNS resolver to get the local hostname, and you encounter a timeout when connecting to it, so:

- either your DNS resolver is configured to a host that is down or filtered by a firewall,
- or the DNS resolver resolves the local host name to an IP that is not the one of your server and is down or filtered by a firewall.

These are the two main cases for which you may have such a timeout, instead of a host unreachable or port unreachable error.

So, replace the line:

```
Socket soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),5217);
```

by this one:

```
Socket soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 5217);
```

to solve your problem.